# Seemingly random StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in supercsv

Tags: scala, supercsv

I am using a supercsv library in my scala code

```
for (row <- readyData) { // tried foreach and map too
  listWriter.write(row)  
}
```

where `readyData` is `Seq[java.util.List[String]]` and `listWriter` is a `CsvListWriter`. I am sometimes getting

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
  at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:197)
  at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)
  at org.supercsv.encoder.DefaultCsvEncoder.encode(DefaultCsvEncoder.java:93)
  at org.supercsv.io.AbstractCsvWriter.escapeString(AbstractCsvWriter.java:102)
  at org.supercsv.io.AbstractCsvWriter.writeRow(AbstractCsvWriter.java:196)
  at org.supercsv.io.AbstractCsvWriter.writeRow(AbstractCsvWriter.java:146)
  at org.supercsv.io.CsvListWriter.write(CsvListWriter.java:71)
  at com.optrak.data.writing.CsvWriting$CsvFileWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(CsvWriting.scala:42)
```

and sometimes

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -28
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:588)
  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:214)
  at org.supercsv.encoder.DefaultCsvEncoder.encode(DefaultCsvEncoder.java:81)
  at org.supercsv.io.AbstractCsvWriter.escapeString(AbstractCsvWriter.java:102)
  at org.supercsv.io.AbstractCsvWriter.writeRow(AbstractCsvWriter.java:196)
  at org.supercsv.io.AbstractCsvWriter.writeRow(AbstractCsvWriter.java:146)
  at org.supercsv.io.CsvListWriter.write(CsvListWriter.java:71)
  at com.optrak.data.writing.CsvWriting$CsvFileWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(CsvWriting.scala:42)
```

with different out-of-bounds indices, usually negative. The last stack frame shown (full output is omitted) points to line 2 of the above code. I am actually using the code in 2 different specs2 test cases. Sometimes both fail, sometimes one. If I get an exception in both test cases, the index which is out of bounds is the same or differs by one. What might be causing this seemingly random behavior, how can I find the cause and make this predictable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an instance of [this bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/bugs/43/) which has been [fixed](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/release_notes.html#a2.2.1) in the latest release (2.2.1).